# Particles and Words Affixing Heads and Phrases

Tags: syntax-trees, morphosyntax, adverbs, clitics

In Malay, there are quite a few words and particles that can affix or modify both heads and phrases. The interrogative suffix -*kah* is one of them.

-*Kah* affixing heads

```
Tidak-kah sakit   kecederaan itu?            NEG
NEG  -Q   painful wound      DIST
Isn't that wound painful?

Dia  makan-kah ayam?                         V
3.SG eat  -Q   chicken?
Does he eat chicken?
```

-*Kah* affixing phrases

```
[Orang  yang mabuk]-kah yang kamu benci?    DP
[Person COMP drunk]-Q   COMP 2.SG hate
Is it drunk people whom you hate?

Dia  berjalan-jalan [di Kuala Lumpur]-kah?  PP
3.SG wander         [in Kuala Lumpur]-Q?
Is he wandering in Kuala Lumpur?
```

My question is this:

> Is there an attested syntactic projection specified for constiutents like this - something like a particle phrase or something? I reckon that the answer has to do with a projection, not in a syntactic tree, but in a morphological tree, since affixes are morphological rather than syntactic and head affixation is involved.

One thing though - certain words can also be as ubiquitous as this interrogative particle, modifying both heads and phrases. The word *juga*, which means *too* can also modify heads.

*Juga* modifying heads

```
Dia  tidak juga terasa sakit                NEG
3.SG NEG   JUGA feel   pain
He didn't really feel any pain

Dia  makan juga ayam                        V
3.SG eat   JUGA chicken
He does eat chicken
```

*Juga* modifying a phrase

```
[Orang  yang mabuk] juga ada  perasaan     DP
[Person COMP drunk] JUGA have feeling
Drunk people too have feelings

[Di sana]  juga kawasan berhantu           PP
[At there] JUGA area    haunted
There too is a haunted area
```

> *Juga* is an adverbial and is a free morpheme. It can't be the case that it occupies a projection at the morphological level, could it?
>   Syntactically, it should occupy an adjunct projection, but what I
>   can't figure out is what kind of projection it should be since adverbs
>   modify VPs, APs, and whole clauses, and *juga* can even modify DPs and
>   PPs and heads like NEG and V. This is somewhat similar tot he question I raised about the adverb also in English: [The Syntax of 'Only'](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/14467/the-syntax-of-only)

Comment: Interesting! It seems that the -*kah* sits next to its scope, and so does *juga*, although I don't understand the (last) chicken example. The overt position of these guys is probably a PF phenomenon. Or else they can be associated with focus projections, where their scope moves -- but I don't know anything about focus in Malay, unfortunately.

Comment: @IvanKapitonov They certainly do have to do with focus. Since they seem to be PF phenomena, I'm starting to think of analysis along the lines of late insertion from Distributed Morphology. Since literature on Malay/Indonesian linguistics is scarce, I can't find anything I can use to help me analyse this.

Can you tell me more about the focus projections you speak of?

Juga modifying the verb in the chicken example is something like "he does too eat chicken".

Comment: 1. I had a cartographic focus in mind, which is a functional projection (often above the vP) that tries to capture dedicated focal positions in a sentence (such as the preverbal focus in Hungarian). Now I don't think that this head should be necessarily tied to a particular position. The relevant constituent would move into its Spec for focus. (I will try to think about a reference). 2. I'm not sure that specifically Late Insertion will help, but something in DM's Morphology component might help indeed. 3. Actually, do you think *dia makan* could be a phonological word?

Comment: There is considerable confusion in English about what things are words and what things are phrases.  Single word subjects are phrases, e.g., and the "single word subjects" at the beginning of this sentence is written with spaces, though it is a compound word.  How do you know that the things you've called phrases are really phrases, and the things you call words are really words?

Comment: @GregLee: Because "eat chicken" is presumably a VP, at least unless we have evidence for the contrary. And "eat" should be it's head.

Comment: @IvanKapitonov, I meant to be asking about Malay, not English.

Comment: @GregLee: I know. Sorry, I should have made it explicit: in Malay *makan ayam* 'eat chicken' is a VP, and *makan* 'eat' is its head.

Comment: @IvanKapitonov, My question above was "How do you know".  How do you know?

Comment: @IvanKapitonov You mean FocP a la Rizzi's split CP analysis? It is understandable for the focus to move to SpecFocP, but how this works with what seems to be focus in-situ ("makan" in "dia makan-kah ayam?") is not at all clear. The only explanation I could think of is the '-kah' suffix affixing the focused constituent (whether it be a phrase/head) and optionally moving to FocP at the left periphery.

Comment: @IvanKapitonov I'm not so sure how to tell whether or not a string is a phonological word without processes such as contraction or cliticization. Do you have any diagnostics I can use?

Anyway, it's hard to think of "dia makan" as a phonological word, unless the subject is cliticised, in which case, the 3.SG pronoun would change into '-nya', a suffixing clitic (never a prefixing clitic). Prefixing clitics are, however, possible with the first and second person pronouns. It doesn't seem impossible for "dia makan" to be a phonological word though.

Comment: @GregLee Well, what I called "a word" is 'juga', which could also be a phrase as it is an adverbial. I don't see how this is relevant though, unless what you're trying to point out is the distinction between a head and a phrase.

Comment: Yes, I meant that sort of FocP. It might (or might not) be possible to get it working with in-situ as well. I'll try to sit down with a pencil and draw these examples when I have a minute. Concerning phonological words, one more diagnostic is a single stress for the whole string. And if only one of the morphological words in it can be (non-contrastively) focused with pitch accent, it would be telling as well. Maybe this discussion should move to a chat room :-)

Comment: I bring up the question of what things are words because you seem to be concerned about whether you're dealing with the structure of words or phrases, i.e., morphology or syntax.  So it might be important to tell them apart.  Just an idea.

Comment: @IvanKapitonov Please do. What I'm thinking of at the moment is Kiss' analysis of English clefts, where she posits that IP selects FocP, which I find rather peculiar. Is that what you have in mind too?

As for phonological words, I think "dia makan" is similar to English "he eats" in terms of stress. What makes the string different from its English counterpart, though, is that it's an acceptable fragment answer to e.g. "does he eat fish?". "Dia makan" (he eats) or simply "makan" (eat) is fine. That could be a clue somehow.

Let's. I don't know how to do that though.

Comment: @GregLee Now I'm getting confused. Lol. What I'm looking to find out is what the interrogative '-kah' is, as it can affix to both heads and phrases. If it really were just a suffix, is it possible for a suffix to affix to whole phrases, i.e. at the syntax level? That seems unlikely, which kinda leads me to the conclusion that '-kah' isn't actually a suffix at the morphological level. It could just be an interrogative particle instead.

Comment: It's unusual for a suffix to attach to a phrase.  The English possessive "'s" attaches to a noun phrase.  E.g., "I'm driving [a man who I used to know]'s car."  When particles start to seem unlike suffixes, they are sometimes termed "clitics".

Comment: @GregLee Excellent. Now that we know (more or less) that '-kah' is a clitic that plays a part in syntax, I want to know how it is parsed in a syntactic tree.

Comment: I don't think that making a nice diagram really tells you how it works, but if you're looking for ideas, you could try McCawley-style trees, which can have crossing lines.  Then, you can put some phrasal constituent inside a word, if you want.  McCawley's proposals can be found in **The Syntactic Phenomena of English**.