# What parts of speech can ‹only› be in English?

Tags: syntax

How is the word ‹only› analyzed in English? It seems unusually flexible.

Consider the following few sentences, each of which use the word ‹only›.

1. Only students read yellow books.
2. Students are the only readers of yellow books.
3. Students read only yellow books.
4. Students only read yellow books.

Sentences (1) and (2) mean the same thing as do (3) and (4). Only appears to function as a determiner phrase in (1) and (3), as an adjective in (2), and as an adverb of some sort in (4). (4) is a bit odd since ‹only› can be interpreted as modifying just the verb rather than the whole predicate in other contexts.

5. Students only read yellow books; they don't write them.
6. *Students read only yellow books; they don't write them.

Comment: Since this question is about a specific word in English, it probably better suited for the [English language and usage SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @lemontree: Digging a little it seems like a duplicate of this question: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/14467/the-syntax-of-only?rq=1 .

Comment: Apart from that: I think that the contrast between 5. and 6. is that the word order in 6. doesn't properly reflect the scope of "only" (it modifies the action and not the object, so it should be placed in front of the verb and not in front of the noun), but this is not necessarily a difference in part of speech.

Comment: Yes, this question seems very similar to yours. If you think that the comments given there answer your question, we could/should close this one. And in case you mentioned the other question as an argument for your question being on-topic too: Peraonally I think that also the related question should actually be on English SE ;)

Comment: @lemontree That makes sense. This is probably the wrong forum for the question as worded. The direction I was hoping one of the answers would take it though is "this is how the type of word that `only` and `even` are function in English" and this is how it compares to other languages.

Comment: The syntax and semantics of _only_ are also [discussed here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/115157/15299).

Comment: "Only" is a focusing adverb in all your examples except 2. where it is an **adjective**. Focusing adverbs can modify virtually every kind of construction, e.g. NPs, PPs, AdjPs, AdvPs, VPs and most clause types. But note that focusing modifiers like "only" modify only NPs (not nouns or nominal). "Readers" is a nominal  (the NP is "the readers") so "only" cannot be a focusing adverb; rather it is an adjective.

Comment: _Only_ is a quantifier, which can float like many quantifiers so that it displays both adjectival and adverbial behaviors. If you prefer to change POS labels when it moves, no problem. Me, I don't think "adverb" is a particularly useful syntactic category anyway; we only have it around because the Romans didn't have a generalized modifier POS like "adjective" to assign adverbs to.

Comment: Did you check a dictionary to see what parts of speech it gives 'only'?

Comment: Notice that your first example is ambiguous (unless intonation is specified) between a sense in which "only" modifies "students" and another in which it modifies the sentence "students read yellow books".  The latter reading means you are taking exception to something that was said earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with Anixx; "only" is an adjective in 2., and an adverb in all other sentences.

The next question would then be, "but are adverbs actually a part of speech, or do we lump several different parts of speech into the category of 'adverb', making it incongruent?"

Answer (score 0):

```
Only students read yellow books.  - adverb
Students are the only readers of yellow books. - adjective
Students read only yellow books. - adverb
Students only read yellow books. - adverb
```

Comment: Why isn't it an adjective in _Students read only yellow books_? It's _only yellow books that they read_, after all.

Comment: @Anixx You are right, and most perceptive! Focusing adverbs do not modify nouns or nominals (as opposed to NPs). In your second example "readers" is a nominal, (the NP is "the readers") so "only" cannot be a focusing adverb. Instead, it is an adjective as you correctly say.

Comment: Answering the question from @jlawler, "yellow books" in the third example is both a NP and an N-bar, so the position of "only" is consistent with it being either an NP modifier (making it an adverb) or an N-bar modifier (making it an adjective).  We can tell which one it is by modifying the example by adding a determiner, which will go after an adverb but before an adjective.

Comment: Also, since *yellow* is indisputedly an adjective, we would expect its position to be interchangeable with other adjectives: *students read pretty yellow books* - *students read yellow pretty books*. This doesn't happen between *yellow* and *only* though; *students read yellow only books* is either agrammatical, or conveys a quite different sense than *students only read yellow books".